# How to keep a process running indefinitely on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

Very new to linux, I am using `screen` to keep running background processes.
For example, I have some Flask REST API's and I run their configuration-file using:

```
uwsgi --ini path_to_file/file.ini
```

Since I have multiple such API's with their individual conf file, I use `screen`. Except for one API all others keep running(for months). All these are almost similar accessing the same database.
This particular API's conf file needs to be restarted everyday.
Is there a proper way to handle running of .ini file?

Using Ubuntu 16 and flask restful

Comment: Turn it into a service (by creating a systemd `.service` file or a script under `/etc/init.d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Panki pointed out in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547864/how-to-keep-a-process-running-indefinitely-on-ubuntu-server#comment1016879_547864) , it's best to create service instead.

But if you want to avoid that as well; write a shell script with all the logic i.e. restarting the particular API config. Then set a cronjob with one day interval on this . 
For setting cronjob with one day interval, open crontab and add below line:

```
30 14 * * * /path/to/your/shell/script
```

This will trigger your script execution at 2:30PM everyday.
For detail on setting cronjob, Refer this answer from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35575322/1944896

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nohup`:

`nohup uwsgi --ini path_to_file/file.ini`

or

make a script with your command and run it with `nohup`

`nohup script.sh &`

This will leave the program running even after closing the terminal.

*Please refer to: https://www.maketecheasier.com/nohup-and-uses/*

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. Nohup is newest thing I learned!