# Ubuntu server process keeps shutting down after some time

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, webserver, hosting-services

I've been starting a web server process using [`nohup`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547874/133783) on a hosted Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS VPS (virtual private server) to make it run in the background and keep it running even if the SSH session is disconnected. However, I noticed numerous times now that the process random stops at some point and I had to re-run it the next day. I'm pretty sure my process didn't crash since I'm using Java and on my local machine it runs indefinitely just fine. The same issue happened with a C++ process and again, locally it never showed any signs of crashes. Is there anything that could cause this issue and what would be the best way to resolve it? I assume it's not related to the hosting only since I have root access.

I've considered using [`immortal`](https://immortal.run) to automatically restart the process when it died which worked but that's not an optimal solution, either, I just want the process to run indefinitely as expected.

Comment: `pretty sure my process didn't crash since I'm using Java` using Java does not ensure your process won't crash. perhaps you could save the stdout/stderr to a file, so you can see if there is any errors when it crashes - I assume Java can handle such a trivial task

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes, I have logging but it doesn't mention anything about a crash. You're right, a Java process is not guaranteed to never crash but Java is a memory safe language so programming mistakes yielding crashes are basically impossible. Furthermore, I observed the exact same issue with a C++ process (as mentioned in the question as well) so I assume it's not related to either process' code directly.

Comment: no, I was addressing the implication that Java never crashes (OK, I misread it) - if it's not crashing, then it's stopping gracefully ... if there are no exceptions, perhaps you need to add some output to your code to troubleshoot why it's stopping gracefully. Personally (not related to your issue), rather than using nohup, I'd create a systemd service.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.